# Serial connection return NULL after first call

Tags: linux, serial-port, arduino, usb, rs485

I'm trying to talk to an arduino via a rs485 serial link. I have a usb to serial rs485 adapter plugged in my pc and a max485 in the arduino side. To get started i simply uploaded a sketch that send back what it receives.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> 
#define SSerialRX        10  //Serial Receive pin
#define SSerialTX        11  //Serial Transmit pin    
#define SSerialTxControl 3   //RS485 Direction control
#define RS485Transmit    HIGH
#define RS485Receive     LOW    
#define Pin13LED         13    

SoftwareSerial RS485Serial(SSerialRX, SSerialTX); // RX, TX    

void setup()
{
  pinMode(Pin13LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SSerialTxControl, OUTPUT);    
  digitalWrite(SSerialTxControl, RS485Receive);
  RS485Serial.begin(300);
}//--(end setup )---    


void loop()
{
  if (RS485Serial.available()){
    delay(100);
    char x = RS485Serial.read();
    digitalWrite(Pin13LED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(SSerialTxControl, RS485Transmit); // Enable RS485 Transmit
    Serial.write(x);
    RS485Serial.write(x); 
    Serial.flush();
    delay(10);
    digitalWrite(SSerialTxControl, RS485Receive);  // Disable RS485 Transmit
    digitalWrite(Pin13LED, LOW);
    delay(200);
  }    

}//--(end main loop )---
```

Then, to test the connection, i run a python script in the pc that writes a character to the serial port and listens to the response:

```
import serial
import time    

PORT1 = "/dev/ttyUSB0"    

try:
    rs485 = serial.Serial(PORT1, 300)
    while True:
        print 'loop'
        rs485.write('r')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        data = rs485.read()
        if data == '\0':
            print 'null'
        else:
            print data
        time.sleep(1)
except:
    rs485.close()
```

The first time I launch the script it happens something like this:

```
giulio@giulio-vaio:~$ python rs485io.py
loop
r
loop
r
loop
^C
```

If i try to launch again the script, it writes nothing more than:

```
giulio@giulio-vaio:~$ python rs485io.py
loop
null
loop
null
loop
null
^C
```

It starts working again only if i reboot my pc (with ubuntu by the way). If i unplug and plug again the usb to serial converter, nothing changes, if i reboot the arduino, same story. I tried the same configuration with a raspberry pi and the result is identical. Changing usb port doesn't work, upload again the same sketch in the arduino, nothing happens.
The led on the pin 13 blinks, so the arduino is receiving and sending something, the serial.read() function returns, so something is arriving, but is (after the first time) a null carachter '\x00'. In one positive case, after rebooting, I tried to let the script go on for a few time and everything went fine, until i hitted ctrl-c and started again the script.

This is dmesg after i plug in the serial converter:

```
[ 6116.508264] usb 1-2.1.3: new full-speed USB device number 27 using ehci-pci
[ 6116.617247] usb 1-2.1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523
[ 6116.617257] usb 1-2.1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 6116.617264] usb 1-2.1.3: Product: USB2.0-Serial
[ 6116.617694] ch341 1-2.1.3:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[ 6116.621498] usb 1-2.1.3: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

I don't know what to do after this, any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT :**

the pc doesn't need to be rebooted, it works if i unload and then load again the module ch341, the one that handles the usb converter.
I added two lines at the top of the code:

```
subprocess.Popen("modprobe -r ch341".split()).wait()
subprocess.Popen("modprobe ch341".split()).wait()
```

I know it doesn't really solve the problem, but it works.

**EDIT 2 :**
Looking at the documentation http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/serial/serial-rs485.txt , I tried to send an ioctl signal to the driver, using this code in c (i'm not good with C, so please forgive me)

```
#include (all the libraries needed)

/* Driver-specific ioctls: */
#define TIOCGRS485      0x542E
#define TIOCSRS485      0x542F
/* Open your specific device (e.g., /dev/mydevice): */    

int main(){
    const char *file1 = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
    const char *file2 = "output_cprog.txt";
    int fd = open (file1,O_WRONLY);
    if(fd < 0){
        printf("%s: %s\n","error opening ttyusb",strerror( errno ) );
    }
    int fq = open(file2,O_WRONLY);
    if( fq < 0){
        printf("%s: %s\n","errore apertura file",strerror( errno ));
    }    

    struct serial_rs485 rs485conf;
     // Enable RS485 mode:
    rs485conf.flags |= SER_RS485_ENABLED;
     // Set logical level for RTS pin equal to 1 when sending:
    rs485conf.flags |= SER_RS485_RTS_ON_SEND;
     // or, set logical level for RTS pin equal to 0 after sending:
    rs485conf.flags &= ~(SER_RS485_RTS_AFTER_SEND);
     // Set rts delay before send, if needed:
    rs485conf.delay_rts_before_send = 10;
     // Set rts delay after send, if needed:
    rs485conf.delay_rts_after_send = 10;
    int ioc = ioctl (fd, TIOCSRS485, &rs485conf);
    if(ioc < 0){
        printf("%i\n",ioc);
        printf("ioctl error: %s\n", strerror( errno ));
    }    

    char *character = "f\n";
    write(fd,character,2);
    char *buffer;
    buffer = (char *) malloc(10);
    read(fd, buffer, 1);
    write(fq, buffer, 1);
    printf("received character: %s\n",buffer[0]);    

    if( close(fd) < 0){
        printf("%s: %s\n","error closing port",strerror( errno ));
    }
    if (close(fq) < 0){
        printf("%s: %s\n","error closing file",strerror( errno ));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but compiling and running the program what i see is only this:

```
giulio@giulio-vaio:~$ ./ioctlRS485.o 
-1
ioctl error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
received character: (null)
```

I think, by looking at the driver https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/usb/serial/ch341.c that it doesn't have the appropriate function to handle an ioctl at all.

Comment: How is the USB-RS485 device's transmit enable driven?  By your problem description it sounds like maybe it's driven by a modem control signal which you are not explicitly controlling.  On your Arduino side you have "SSerialTxControl" but I see nothing corresponding on the PC side.  Does your converter attempt an automatic time/activity-based control of it?

Comment: i tried with the flags rtscts=True and dsrdtr=True in serial.serial() but nothing changes. Samething if I put setRTS(True) and setRTS(False) before and after calling serial.write('').
Actually i found a functional workaround, i'll edit the first post with it. It's not so clean, but it works.

Comment: Sure you aren't advancing to a new device, ie /dev/ttyUSB1 and so on, on each re-plug?  There are many fronts you could attack this on: using a terminal emulator instead of your python client, monitoring the signals with a scope, adding things to the source of the serial driver, etc.

Comment: Yes, i checked every time the name of the device, sometimes it changes, sometimes not, but it seems that it doesn't make any difference for this case. I tried with a terminal emulator but nothing relevant emerged. Sure i won't stop looking for a better solution!

Comment: Usually the Linux serial port driver has to be configured into RS-485 mode using the **TIOCSRS485** ioctl.  This ioctl takes a data structure that specifies how the RTS handshake signal is repurposed and should control the transmitter.  Read http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/serial/serial-rs485.txt  Just because the HW is RS-485, you should not assume that the software side(s) has(have) been automatically configured into a proper state (on either end of the serial link).

Comment: Seems to me that ch341.h doesn't contain the appropriate function to handle an ioctl signal. I rewrited (part of) the code in C, using the sample code in the documentation, and now I'm sending the TIOCSRS485 flag. But i continue to get "Inappropriate ioctl for device".